# DAX model invoice running balance

Tags: powerpivot, dax, powerbi

I have a table with invoices and a table with payments. The Invoice table consists of invoice id, amount, invoice date, expiry date. The payment table consists of invoice id, amount, payment date. The invoice table have an active relationship with the date table on the expiry date column. The payment table have an active relationship with the invoice table on the invoice id columns.

I would like to be able to show the invoice balance on an arbitrary day. Ie if I filter the report or page on a particular date I'd like to see the acual balance on that day per invoice. Anyone know how to acomplish this without creating a new table and programmatically fill it with invoice balance per day entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
InvoiceTotalAmount:=
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Invoice[Amount])
    ,ALL(DimDate) // The active relationship between Invoice[ExpiryDate]
                  // and DimDate[Date] would cause this to only be valid
                  // on the expiry date - we don't want that.
)

PaymentTotalToDate:=
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE( // We'll manipulate the relationship in the inner
               // CALCULATE() before modifying context based on it
        SUM(Payment[Amount])
        ,USERELATIONSHIP(Payment[Date], DimDate[Date])
   )
    ,FILTER( // Now that that we're looking at the right relationship to
             // DimDate, we can alter the date range in context
        ALL(DimDate)
        ,DimDate[Date] <= MAX(DimDate[Date])
            // Here, we take all dates less than the latest date in
            // context in the pivot table - current date if 1 date in
            // context, else last of week, month, quarter, etc....
    )
)

InvoiceBalanceToDate:=[InvoiceTotalAmount] - [PaymentTotalToDate]
```

If you're not utilizing that active relationship between Invoice[ExpiryDate] and DimDate[Date], I'd mark it as inactive and the relationship between Payment[Date] and DimDate[Date] as the active one. You could then dispense with the CALCULATE() and ALL() in [InvoiceTotalAmount] and the inner CALCULATE() in [PaymentTotalToDate].

My model diagram:
[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for taking the time to answer. My model diagram looks exactly the same. When I plug in your solution I get a warning when trying to create the calculated column "InvoiceBalanceToDate", the warning says "A circular dependency was detected: Payment[PaymentTotalToDate], Payment[Column], Payment[PaymentTotalToDate]." I'm using the latest version of Power BI Desktop. Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't want to create these as calculated columns, but as measures.
[See this image for two ways to create a measure](http://i.imgur.com/SzudqTT.png)

[Here is a good post describing measures vs columns - note that Power BI, Power Pivot, and SSAS Tabular all use the same storage engine, the same query language, and have the same behavior](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/02/when-to-use-measures-vs-calc-columns/)

Comment: Thanks, measures seems to work. I modified the InvoiceTotalAmount measure so it's filtered with MAX(Date) just like the PaymentTotalToDate, ie InvoiceTotalToDate instead of InvoiceTotalAmount, so I can go back in time and see the balance per that date.

Comment: Sure - it was unclear how you'd be reporting on this, so I wasn't sure how to handle the invoice part. I'm glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a measure in the date table that uses CALCULATETABLE function to calculate the remaining balance of an invoice on that day.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634760(v=sql.105).aspx