# Averaging a measure/create a table from measure DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi

I have a measure calculating the running balance of invoices, see this question [DAX model invoice running balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902756/dax-model-invoice-running-balance). Now I would like to be able to average the running balance filtered by the query context.

Ie Id like somehow to return a table using DateDim with a calculated invoice balance per day and average over that table using the selected period in the query context. I've tried some solutions but really haven't found a smart way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AveragedRunningBalance:=
AVERAGEX(
    DimDate
    ,[InvoiceBalanceToDate]
)
```

This will step row-by-row through the dates in context (logical and of the rowfilter, columnfilter, slicer, and filter selections in the pivot), calculating [InvoiceBalanceToDate] for each row in that table, and accumulating those individual results in an average (sum of individuals divided by number of dates in DimDate in context).

Comment: Thanks once again. Looks simple now that you wrote the answer. I clearly don't understand how the X functions work.